# Can a page have more than one document.ready function?

Tags: javascript

I have wondered/worried about this for a while now, so I thought I'd ask someone who knows for sure.  Can a page have more than one document.ready function?  Will they both be executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they will **both** be executed. You can assign [multiple](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aMultiple_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29) [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event handlers to a `document`. When the DOM is ready, jQuery will trigger any bound ready events. From the source:

```
// Handle when the DOM is ready
ready: function( wait ) {
    ...
    // Trigger any bound ready events
    if ( jQuery.fn.trigger ) {
      jQuery( document ).trigger("ready").off("ready");
    }
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RQCm4/1/)**.

Answer (score 4):

`document.ready` isn't as standard DOM handler but you're probably referring to [the jQuery utility](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) that you're calling as `$(document).ready(...`

It adds the function to a queue so that you may call this function many times with different callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have multiple `document.ready` function on a page.They run in sequential order one after the another based on their occurrence in the code.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     alert("hello 1");
 });
 $(document).ready(function() {
     alert("hello 2");
 })
```

;